# Linearizing the following equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linearization, delay-differential-equations

I'm working through a section in a book I'm reading about delay differential equations (Semi-discretization for time delay systems, Springer), and the authors are discussing the following equation
$$\left(\frac13ml^2-\frac14ml^2\cos^2\phi\right) \ddot{\phi} +\frac18mgl^2\dot{\phi}^2\sin(2\phi)- \frac12mgl\sin\phi\\
 = -\frac12l\cos\phi (k_p\phi(t-\tau)+k_d\dot{\phi}(t-\tau)),$$where $m$, $l$, $g$, $\tau$, $k_d$ and $k_p$ are all constants.

They say that linearizing about $\phi = 0$ reduces the equation to 
$$\frac{1}{12}ml^2\ddot{\phi}-\frac12mgl\phi = -\frac12l(K_p\phi(t-\tau)+K_d\dot{\phi}(t-\tau)),$$

But I'm not really familiar with linearization of second order equations and I am having trouble finding useful resources regarding the matter. Can anyone show me how to linearize the first equation? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me where the $\dot{\phi}$'s went.

Comment: Oops, I had forgotten the dot over the $\phi$ on the right hand side. But the other term including $\dot{\phi}^2$ on the LHS is indeed intended to be missing after linearization.

Comment: It's just using $\cos\phi =1$ and $\sin\phi=\phi$, but without any other conditions I don't know why $\dot\phi^2\sin{2\phi}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the equation to values close to $0$ can be realized by setting $ϕ=\epsilon u$ for some small scale $ϵ\approx 0$ and then removing any terms that are of a higher order in $ϵ$. Insert and divide by $ϵ$,
\begin{multline}
ml^2\left(\frac13−\frac14\cos^2(ϵu)\right)\ddot u + \frac18mgl^2ϵ\dot u^2\sin(2ϵu)−\frac12mgl\frac{\sin(ϵu)}{ϵ}
\\=−\frac12l\cos(ϵu)(k_pu(t−τ)+k_d\dot u(t−τ)).
\end{multline}
Now assuming that $u$ has moderate values, $|u|\ll ϵ^{-1}$, the Taylor series of the trigonometric functions provide 
$$\cos(ϵu)=1+O(ϵ^2),  ~~  \frac{\sin(ϵu)}{ϵ}=u+O(ϵ^2),  ~~ ϵ\sin(2ϵu)=O(ϵ^2).$$ So up to $ϵ^2$-small terms 
$$
ml^2\frac1{12}\ddot u −\frac12mglu=−\frac12l(k_pu(t−τ)+k_d\dot u(t−τ)).
$$
or rescaled to the scale of $ϕ$,
$$
ml^2\frac1{12}\ddot ϕ −\frac12mglϕ=−\frac12l(k_pϕ(t−τ)+k_d\dot ϕ(t−τ)).
$$

Comment: Your answer is great, but just one remark. In the first term in the equation you have $\cos(2\epsilon u)$, when I think you should really have $\cos^2(\epsilon u)$. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I did not see that, should have copied the TeX-version of the formula.